# Exporting mxd to image with transparent background from ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, mxd, transparency-opacity, png

I cannot get ArcMap 10.0 or 10.1 to "Export Map" to a png or gif with a transparent background -- no matter what I set the background and transparent colors to.  Thus, I created the following script, which does the trick, but I'd rather be able to get the default tool in ArcMap to do it.  Any better ideas?

---

```
# Purpose: This script exports an MXD view to a png file with transparent background,
# which is problematic to do manually due to a Windows-related bug in the ArcMap UI.
# Warning: It will make any white features (e.g. the default background color) transparent.
#
# INSTRUCTIONS:
# When in ArcMap, viewing a saved mxd...
# 1. From the Geoprocessing menu, select 'Python'.
# 2. In the new Python window, right-click somewhere after >>>, and select 'Load...'
# 3. Select this script.
# 4. When this script appears, press Enter twice to run it.
# 5. A new [mxd-name].png with transparent background will appear in the same directory as the mxd.
# 6. When finished/satisfied, close the Python window.
# http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65463-Zoom-to-tile-and-Export-to-JPEG-with-World-File
import arcpy
png_resolution = 300    # Can adjust DPI
# Set mxd and png name
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
pngname = mxd.filePath.replace(".mxd",".png")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
# Calculate ideal image size from the mxd view and desired DPI
png_width = int((df.extent.XMax - df.extent.XMin) * png_res * 12 / df.scale)
png_height = int((df.extent.YMax - df.extent.YMin) * png_res * 12 / df.scale)
#Export PNG
print "Exporting: {0}\n{1} x {2} pixels, {3}-dpi".format(pngname,png_width,png_height,png_res)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, pngname, df, df_export_width = png_width, df_export_height = png_height, resolution = png_res, transparent_color = "255, 255, 255")
#Clean up
del df, pngname, png_res, png_width, png_height, mxd
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just gave this a test using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 on Windows 7 SP1 and was able to create a PNG and GIF files that had a transparent background that I could verify by inserting them as pictures into Word 2010 as In Front Of Text.

I followed the Exporting your map instructions from the [ArcGIS 10.1 Online Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sm00000004000000), using Rose Quartz as both Background and Transparent Color, doing so from both Data and Layout View, and otherwise taking all defaults.

> PNG and GIF support transparency. They have a Transparent Color
>   option, which selects the color in the map that will be marked as
>   transparent. If you want to make only the background of the map image
>   transparent, set Background Color and Transparent Color to the same
>   color.

If at all possible, I would recommend upgrading to ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 (or testing this on another machine with that version to decide whether you want to).

Comment: I didn't try any other color than white, but I tried all combinations of the background and transpancy colors (in white) and this problem exists on at least 3 machines in our network, one running v.10.0 and 2 with v.10.1. I suppose I can try a different color, but having to select another color is definitely a kludge. I don't know when our techs will OK the move to 10.2. Guess we'll see.

Comment: I don't think the color is important because I just retested using white (Arctic White on color palette) and that seemed fine too.

Comment: Update: Using rose quartz didn't help. I guess we'll have to wait for 10.2.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't create a PNG map with transparent background using ArcMap 10.4 using > File > Export. If I set the background colour to None, export, and re-open the dialog, the background colour no longer has the slash through it the way that Transparent Colour does. See [image](http://i.imgur.com/mq65lI8.png "image")

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a few variables being inconsistently named this worked flawlessly.

```
# which is problematic to do manually due to a Windows-related bug in the ArcMap UI.
# Warning: It will make any white features (e.g. the default background color) transparent.
#
# INSTRUCTIONS:
# When in ArcMap, viewing a saved mxd...
# 1. From the Geoprocessing menu, select 'Python'.
# 2. In the new Python window, right-click somewhere after >>>, and select 'Load...'
# 3. Select this script.
# 4. When this script appears, press Enter twice to run it.
# 5. A new [mxd-name].png with transparent background will appear in the same directory as the mxd.
# 6. When finished/satisfied, close the Python window.
# http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/65463-Zoom-to-tile-and-Export-to-JPEG-with-World-   

File
import arcpy
png_res = 150    # Can adjust DPI
# Set mxd and png name
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
pngname = mxd.filePath.replace(".mxd",".png")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
# Calculate ideal image size from the mxd view and desired DPI
png_width = int((df.extent.XMax - df.extent.XMin) * png_res * 12 / df.scale)
png_height = int((df.extent.YMax - df.extent.YMin) * png_res * 12 / df.scale)
#Export PNG
print "Exporting: {0}\n{1} x {2} pixels, {3}- dpi".format(pngname,png_width,png_height,png_res)
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG(mxd, pngname, df, df_export_width = png_width,     df_export_height = png_height, resolution = png_res, transparent_color = "255, 255, 255")
#Clean up
del df, pngname, png_res, png_width, png_height, mxd
```